# I receive this error and I can not understand why: sub scripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector|

Tags: arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
char f(const char a,int size,int i);

int main(void)
{
   int i,j=-1;
   char string1[20];
   char string2[20];
   int ch;
   char m;
   gets(string1);
   for(i=0;i<20;i++)
   {
     if(('a'<string1[i]<'z')||('A'<string1[i]<'Z'))
     {
        printf("%c",string1[i]);
     }    
   }
   char f(const char a,int size,int i)
   {
      if(i==1)
      {
          printf("%c",a[i]);
      }
      else
      { 
          f(a,size,i-1);
          printf("%c",a[i]);
      }    
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I recieve this error for 2 times and I can not understant why: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.
this error was for my function in the end of this code.it returns to the 2  printf  in the functions body

Comment: you may want to add a tag for which language you are using - to get more views and answers. I don't know much about C, but is it possible that you are missing a `}` before your `f` function?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to build here there is no logic to your program. You have defined a recursive function but haven't called it anywhere.
Also avoid using 'gets' function instead try using 'fgets' it asks for the number of characters you want to scan so it's more dynamic.

'gets' function waits for you the compiler to point to next line(i.e pressing enter) that can be tricky. It is preferred for command line interface.